# How do I capture XML out in PHP

Tags: php, html, xml

I am using a sms gateway i.e. sms4connect. Sms are sending successfully. Now the problem is I want to save the sms sending results into my table and then fetch the results.

Here is my php code :

```
<?php

$num = "92xxxxxxxxxx";
$mes = "Hello World (&) and a 5 note"; 

// Configuration variables 
$type = "xml"; 
$id = "myid"; 
$pass = "mypass"; 
$lang = "English"; 
$mask = "mymask"; 

// Data for text message 
$to = $num ; 
$message = $mes; 
$message = urlencode($message);   

// Prepare data for POST request
 $data = "id=".$id."&pass=".$pass."&msg=".$message."&to=".$to."&lang=".$lang."&mask=".$mask."&type=".$type;   

 // Send the POST request with cURL 
 $ch = curl_init('http://www.sms4connect.com/api/sendsms.php/sendsms/url'); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
 $result = curl_exec($ch); //This is the result from SMS4CONNECT curl_close($ch);
 echo $result;
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sms_response (phone, msg) values('$to','$result')");

?>
```

and I am getting the message "(300 Success Message Sent to Telecom. 239133150)". I want to save this message against each number into my database table. As you see in my PHP code that I am inserting $to, $result values in sms_response table but instead of saving number and message, I am getting these values in my table as shown in the image.
[image]

So How can I save message and Phone into my table correctly. Help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: Can you please show your XML output?

Comment: 1. Don't use the deprecated and insecure `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: You're doing it wrongly. You already have the message `$message` and the phone number `$num` with you. Why don't you use those in your query upon successfully sending the SMS?

Comment: If you want to store the response message, you need to extract it from the XML response first.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson I am getting this message "300 Success Message Sent to Telecom. 239133150" and I am supposing its an xml response.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($result)` and check "view source" on the page and you should see what the actual response is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an XML object by this script

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($result) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
print_r($xml);
```

In $xml you will get all the data fetched from the sms gateway. Which you can retrieve and save in DB.

`simplexml_load_string` it creates XML object from given XML string.

If you are getting a success message in  node in your XML, you can simply retrieve the data like

```
$successMessage = $xml->message;
```

Save this `$successMessage` message in your db column. Please replace message with related field in your XML response. This is just an example.

### Update

To store a phone number along with message you can concat them like

```
$successMessage = $num.": ".$xml->message;
```

This is just an example. You can concat them in any format. While retrieving the message if you want to get the phone number from the message you can explode the string by ":"

```
$msg = explode(":",$message_column);
echo $msg[0]; //phone number
echo $msg[1]; //message
```

Comment: Thanks @Smit Raval. How I will store $xml object data into my database table.

Comment: Thanks buddy. One more problem. could you tell me how to insert phone number along with this message. As i am getting transaction id in my phone number field

Comment: You want to store phone number in your message column along with success message?

Comment: Yes But I am getting transaction Id instead of phone number